# Why does $\delta g^{\mu\nu}=0$ on a boundary imply that the tangential derivative of $\delta g^{\mu\nu}=0$ too?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, boundary-conditions, boundary-terms

In https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4033, between Eq. (4.2) and (4.3), the authors state that setting $\delta g^{\mu\nu}=0$ on a boundary implies that the tangential derivative $h^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha\delta g^{\mu\nu}=0$ as well.

1. Is there some intuitive way to see this? The best answer that I can come up with is that if we demand that $\delta g^{\mu\nu}=0$ at points A and B on the boundary, and we are free to choose points A and B to be arbitrarily close together, then the variation (e.g. derivative) of $\delta g^{\mu\nu}$ between points A and B can be made arbitrarily small, which implies $h^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha\delta g^{\mu\nu}=0$ everywhere on the boundary. (I feel that there should be a more elegant way to understand this.)
2. If instead of considering $\delta g^{\mu\nu}=0$ on the boundary, if I had a scalar field $\phi$, and I demand that $\delta\phi=0$ on the boundary, can I use the same line of reasoning as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any function $f$ is constant (in particular zero) on a surface $S$, then $S$ is by definition a level set of $f$. The gradient of $f$ is perpendicular to its level sets, or equivalently, the directional derivative along $S$ is zero. This is proven in any multivariable calculus textbook.